Reactアプリでホットリロードが機能しない
環境構築を行い、コードを変更して保存しても、ブラウザに変更が反映されません。
開発サーバーは正常に動作しているように見えますが、変更が自動的に更新されません。
試したこと:

npx create-react-app my-app cd my-app npm start
npm startで開発サーバーを再起動しました。
ブラウザのキャッシュをクリアし、シークレットモードで試しました。
node_modulesを削除して再インストールしました。
PORT=3001 npm startで試しました
ブラウザのデベロッパーツールを開き、コンソールにもエラーがありませんでした
VSCodeの自動保存機能が有効です
WATCHPACK_POLLING=true npm startにてホットリロード出来るようになりましたが、
根本的原因解決をしたいです

環境情報:

React: 18.3.1
Node.js: v18.19.1
OS: macOS Sonoma 14.6.1
エディタ: Visual Studio Code バージョン: 1.95.3

期待する結果:
コードを保存した際に、ブラウザが自動で更新されることを期待しています。

解決しました
仮想環境だということを失念していました
その場合、Create React App公式よりCHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=trueかWATCHPACK_POLLING=trueあれば大丈夫そうです
